# How do I get the Euler Angle difference from one object position to anothers orientation

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, vector, euler-angles

I'm looking to find the Euler angle difference (on one axis) between a targets position relative to the players orientation and position.

Hopefully the below image will help illustrate what I want.

[image: Euler Angle]

What I have attempted so far is this

```
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject target;

    Vector3 targetDir = target.transform.position - player.transform.position;
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(player.transform.forward, targetDir);
    Debug.Log(angle);
```

This will output the angle between 0-180, no matter if its on the left and right.

What I want is the euler angle, so the angle should be represented between 0 to 360 degrees.

I have tried converting the angles to Quaternions but I'm getting inconsistent results. The number goes from very low to high with a small amount of movement in the console

```
var testRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(player.transform.forward,target.transform.position - player.transform.position);
Debug.Log(testRotation.eulerAngles.y);
```

I have tried doing this using vector3 and dot

```
  Vector3 targetDir = player.transform.position - target.transform.position;
    var rot = Mathf.Cos(Vector3.Dot(player.transform.forward, targetDir.normalized));
    Debug.Log(rot);
```

but this will output a number between 0.5 and 0.999

Using Draco18s answer I ended up creating this method (which is far from perfect). It worked for me.

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculate angle difference on the Y axis between one object (target) and anothers (player) orientation and position as an angle between 0 & 360 degrees
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_target"></param>
/// <param name="_player"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private float CalcAngle(GameObject _target, GameObject _player)
{
    //Calculate the direction of the target removing any up or down rotation
    Vector3 _newDirection = (new Vector3(_target.transform.position.x, 0, _target.transform.position.z) - new Vector3(_player.transform.position.x, 0, _player.transform.position.z));

    // the vector that we want to measure an angle from
    Vector3 referenceForward = _player.transform.forward;/* some vector that is not Vector3.up */
    // Remove any up or down rotation
    referenceForward = new Vector3(referenceForward.x, 0, referenceForward.z);

    // the vector perpendicular to referenceForward (90 degrees clockwise)
    // (used to determine if angle is positive or negative)
    Vector3 referenceRight = _player.transform.right;
    referenceRight = new Vector3(referenceRight.x, 0, referenceRight.z);

    // Get the angle in degrees between 0 and 180
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(_newDirection, referenceForward);

    // Determine if the degree value should be negative. Here, a positive value
    // from the dot product means that our vector is on the right of the reference vector
    // whereas a negative value means we're on the left.
    float sign = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(_newDirection, referenceRight));

    // Create an angle between 0-360
    float result = sign * angle;
    if (result < 0)
    {
        result = 360 - Mathf.Abs(result);
    }
    //Give back the result
    return result;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your method is not enough - you will lose one degree of freedom (the rotation *around* the vector itself). Convert the angles to quaternions and go from there.

Comment: I have given this a try, I'm perhaps using the wrong function

Comment: You could calculate the angle yourself by doing `dot(player.forward, targetDir.normalized)`   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654315/how-to-convert-a-dot-product-of-two-vectors-to-the-angle-between-the-vectors

Comment: Hi, I've given this a try as well with no luck

Comment: I believe your target direction math is wrong it should be `target - origin`.  The range of the dot product of 2 normalized vectors is `-1 - 1`

Comment: Hi, swapped it round. Its still not the answer I need. I'm also looking for this to be represented as 0-360 degrees (on one axis)

Comment: I don't think you formulated the question correctly. There is nothing like the Euler angle difference between positions (or directions ?). Are you asking about one angle, two or three ?

Comment: I'm asking for one angle.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a dupe-target somewhere, but I can't find it.

I can, however, find some code that I got from...somewhere a number of years ago, complete with comments.

```
private float CalcAngle(Vector3 newDirection) {
    // the vector that we want to measure an angle from
    Vector3 referenceForward = transform.forward;/* some vector that is not Vector3.up */

    // the vector perpendicular to referenceForward (90 degrees clockwise)
    // (used to determine if angle is positive or negative)
    Vector3 referenceRight = transform.right;

    // Get the angle in degrees between 0 and 180
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(newDirection, referenceForward);

    // Determine if the degree value should be negative. Here, a positive value
    // from the dot product means that our vector is on the right of the reference vector
    // whereas a negative value means we're on the left.
    float sign = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(newDirection, referenceRight));

    return sign * angle;
}
```

This will give you a value from -180 to +180.  Converting that to 0-360 will require a little math, but should be straight forward (hint: -179.99 -> +180.01).

Comment: Thank you for the response, the method requires a Vector3 'newDirection', would you mind clearing up what that is for me and how I might get it?

Comment: I'm assuming its something like         float angle = CalcAngle(target.transform.position - player.transform.position);
        Debug.Log(angle);

Comment: @Jim it's the vector that point towards the target, the direction you want to measure *to.* The referenceForward is the vector to measure from. So yes, you have it correct. You should probably normalize it though.

Comment: Cheers @Draco18s why do you suggestion I normalize it?

Comment: @Jim As it's a direction vector: You there's no need to keep the magnitude. Also, the math might not work correctly on a non-normalized vector, I'm not sure. It's been 3 or 4 years since I messed with the project I pulled that from.